# How to properly select an element inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectors, angular-directive

If I define a `link` function for my angular directive, what is the best way to select a particular element inside of the directive? For example, if this is my template url:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

and I want to select the `input`, what is the best way to get a reference to the `input` tag in my link function?

My initial thoughts was to put an `id` attribute on the `input` tag and select based on that, but since this is a directive I wont necessarily know where it is used, so whatever id I choose may not be unique.

Comment: I believe the best would be creating an attribute for the directive and dynamically associate it to the control that you want. this way you'd always know the field you are dealing with.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes If I understand you correctly, I dont think thats a good idea. This is an internal implementation detail that should not concern the user of the directive. Whoever uses this won't care what internal element is being selected or how.

Comment: hmm.. makes sense :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use the angular element object, it has built in jqlite functions, and for a not unique element or something jQlite doesn't support you can always get the pure DOM and use querySelector ej:

```
app.directive("directiveName",function()
{
   return{
     template : "<div><span class='aclass'><button>hi</button></span></div>",
     link ( scope, ele, attr){
       var a = ele.find('button');
       console.log(a);
       var b= ele[0].querySelector('.aclass')  //element[0] for the DOM
       console.log(b);
     }
   };
});
```

here is a list of jqlite functions you can use with the element object
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element